# Using calls to update "calls" to functions in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, call

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to use calls in R.  I want to take an object created by a function and use it as an argument to another function, modifying some of the arguments to the original function along the way.  I've looked at [Hadley Wickham's page on expressions,](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html) but it doesn't quite seem to tell me how to do what I want to do.

Here is a partially-working example of the sort of thing that I want to do.  First, fake data:

```
library(MASS)
N <- 1000
p <- 10
A <- matrix(rnorm(p^2), p)
X <- mvrnorm(N, rep(0, p), t(A) %*% A)
B <- rnorm(p)
y <- X %*% B + rnorm(N)
```

Next, a function to do ridge regression.  It is a function of `X`, `y`, and the ridge penalty `L`.  It returns the coefs and the call:

```
pols <- function(X, y, L){
  cl <- match.call()
  beta <- solve(t(X) %*% X + diag(rep(L, p))) %*% t(X) %*% y
  return(list(beta = beta, cl = cl))
}

1> pols(X, y, 1)
$beta
             [,1]
 [1,] -0.02622669
 [2,] -1.96523722
 [3,]  0.36375563
 [4,] -1.14192468
 [5,] -0.14436051
 [6,] -0.29700918
 [7,] -0.81543748
 [8,] -0.17699934
 [9,] -0.01342649
[10,]  0.58862577

$cl
pols(X = X, y = y, L = 1)
```

Now, how do I use the call to drive the following function?  It takes a `pols` object and a vector of different values of `L` and uses them to re-call `pols`

```
Lvec <- 1:10    
tryLs <- function(pols, Lvec){
      for (i in Lvec){
        1.  Extract the args from the call in pols
        2.  Modify the argument `L` based on Lvec
        3.  Run `pols` with old arguments, but `L` modified according to `i`
      }
    }
```

How do I make this last function work?

To clarify, the workflow I'm envisioning is something like:

```
obj <- pols(X, y, 0)
Lvec <- 1:10
output <- tryLs(obj, Lvec)
```

Comment: So, the call is `pols(X = X, y = y, L = 1)`.  Take those arguments such that they can be modified in the second step.  So like make `L<-2`

Comment: This is just a dummy example for SO.  My real code is far more complex.  Basically I've got a really long list of arguments, and I only want to modify one of them.  I'd have to loop over `pols(q,w,e,r,t,y,u,,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make a few guesses/assumptions here.

(1) When you say "a pols object", you mean an object returned by the `pols` function.  I've modified `pols()` below so that it returns an object of type "pols".  This isn't at all necessary, but might be useful in the future if you want to do fancier things (e.g. implement custom printing or plotting methods for these objects).

Setup:

```
library(MASS)
N <- 1000
p <- 10
A <- matrix(rnorm(p^2), p)
X <- mvrnorm(N, rep(0, p), t(A) %*% A)
B <- rnorm(p)
y <- X %*% B + rnorm(N)
```

I'm also modifying `pols` so that the element containing the call is called `call`: this makes the objects automatically work with R's default `update` method.

```
pols <- function(X, y, L){
   cl <- match.call()
   beta <- solve(t(X) %*% X + diag(rep(L, p))) %*% t(X) %*% y
   r <- list(beta = beta, call = cl)
   class(r) <- "pols"
   return(r)
}
```

In order to have a `pols` object we have to run `pols()` once and save the result:

```
pols1 <- pols(X,y,0)
```

Now here's your function. My second assumption is that you only want the `$beta` values returned ...

```
tryLs <- function(pols,Lvec) {
    sapply(Lvec,
           function(L) update(pols,L=L)$beta)
}
Lvec <- 1:10
tryLs(pols1,Lvec)
```

If you wanted to do this at a slightly more nuts-and-bolts level (rather than using `update`) you would do something along the lines of

```
pols$call$L <- new_L_value
new_result <- eval(pols$call,parent.frame())
```

If you look at `update.default()` you'll see that's more or less what it does (it *is* using the information from `match.call()`, implicitly ...)

Comment: Interesting.  You didn't use the info in `match.call`.  I guess my prior was that the whole purpose of saving the call was for various sorts of updating.

Answer (score 1):

If I guess correctly as to what you need, I would use `partial` from the `pryr` package. This allows you to create a function with a number of the arguments already set:

```
library(pryr)
preset_pols = partial(pols, X = preset_X, y = preset_y)
preset_pols(L = 1)
```

calling `preset_pols` will now always use the data specified in `preset_X` and `preset_y`.

In my opinion there is no need for the `for` loop, `lapply` would do just fine here:

```
list_of_results = lapply(Lvec, preset_pols)
```

Comment: That works great, thanks.  But I'm surprised that there is no solution in base R.  What is the point of `match.call()` if not to save the arguments for re-evaluation later?

Comment: You can use `do.call` to run a function with a `list` of arguments. Just use a list with the preset arguments and append the `L = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lvec <- 1:10    
tryLs <- function(pols, Lvec){
  for (i in Lvec){
    print(paste("Result for ",i))
    print(pols(X,y,i))$beta
    print(pols(X,y,i))$cl

  }
}

tryLs(pols,Lvec)
```

> ```
> [1] "Result for  1"
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,]  0.03317113
>  [2,] -0.37399461
>  [3,] -1.35395755
>  [4,]  0.09850883
>  [5,] -0.14503628
>  [6,] -1.97204600
>  [7,] -0.56459244
>  [8,] -1.10422047
>  [9,] -0.92047748
> [10,]  1.76236287
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,]  0.03317113
>  [2,] -0.37399461
>  [3,] -1.35395755
>  [4,]  0.09850883
>  [5,] -0.14503628
>  [6,] -1.97204600
>  [7,] -0.56459244
>  [8,] -1.10422047
>  [9,] -0.92047748
> [10,]  1.76236287
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> [1] "Result for  2"
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.01014376
>  [2,] -0.32064189
>  [3,] -1.29381243
>  [4,]  0.10695047
>  [5,] -0.24791384
>  [6,] -1.83662948
>  [7,] -0.55615073
>  [8,] -1.12204424
>  [9,] -0.96717380
> [10,]  1.79084625
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.01014376
>  [2,] -0.32064189
>  [3,] -1.29381243
>  [4,]  0.10695047
>  [5,] -0.24791384
>  [6,] -1.83662948
>  [7,] -0.55615073
>  [8,] -1.12204424
>  [9,] -0.96717380
> [10,]  1.79084625
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> [1] "Result for  3"
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.04097765
>  [2,] -0.28237279
>  [3,] -1.25064282
>  [4,]  0.11286963
>  [5,] -0.32135783
>  [6,] -1.74000917
>  [7,] -0.55025764
>  [8,] -1.13481390
>  [9,] -1.00038377
> [10,]  1.81099139
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.04097765
>  [2,] -0.28237279
>  [3,] -1.25064282
>  [4,]  0.11286963
>  [5,] -0.32135783
>  [6,] -1.74000917
>  [7,] -0.55025764
>  [8,] -1.13481390
>  [9,] -1.00038377
> [10,]  1.81099139
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> [1] "Result for  4"
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.06401718
>  [2,] -0.25352501
>  [3,] -1.21807596
>  [4,]  0.11721395
>  [5,] -0.37641945
>  [6,] -1.66761823
>  [7,] -0.54595545
>  [8,] -1.14442668
>  [9,] -1.02517135
> [10,]  1.82592968
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.06401718
>  [2,] -0.25352501
>  [3,] -1.21807596
>  [4,]  0.11721395
>  [5,] -0.37641945
>  [6,] -1.66761823
>  [7,] -0.54595545
>  [8,] -1.14442668
>  [9,] -1.02517135
> [10,]  1.82592968
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> [1] "Result for  5"
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.08186374
>  [2,] -0.23095555
>  [3,] -1.19257456
>  [4,]  0.12050945
>  [5,] -0.41923287
>  [6,] -1.61137106
>  [7,] -0.54271257
>  [8,] -1.15193566
>  [9,] -1.04434740
> [10,]  1.83739926
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.08186374
>  [2,] -0.23095555
>  [3,] -1.19257456
>  [4,]  0.12050945
>  [5,] -0.41923287
>  [6,] -1.61137106
>  [7,] -0.54271257
>  [8,] -1.15193566
>  [9,] -1.04434740
> [10,]  1.83739926
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> [1] "Result for  6"
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.09607715
>  [2,] -0.21277987
>  [3,] -1.17201761
>  [4,]  0.12307151
>  [5,] -0.45347618
>  [6,] -1.56641949
>  [7,] -0.54021027
>  [8,] -1.15797228
>  [9,] -1.05959733
> [10,]  1.84644233
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>              [,1]
>  [1,] -0.09607715
>  [2,] -0.21277987
>  [3,] -1.17201761
>  [4,]  0.12307151
>  [5,] -0.45347618
>  [6,] -1.56641949
>  [7,] -0.54021027
>  [8,] -1.15797228
>  [9,] -1.05959733
> [10,]  1.84644233
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> [1] "Result for  7"
> $beta
>             [,1]
>  [1,] -0.1076495
>  [2,] -0.1977993
>  [3,] -1.1550561
>  [4,]  0.1251007
>  [5,] -0.4814888
>  [6,] -1.5296799
>  [7,] -0.5382458
>  [8,] -1.1629381
>  [9,] -1.0719931
> [10,]  1.8537217
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>             [,1]
>  [1,] -0.1076495
>  [2,] -0.1977993
>  [3,] -1.1550561
>  [4,]  0.1251007
>  [5,] -0.4814888
>  [6,] -1.5296799
>  [7,] -0.5382458
>  [8,] -1.1629381
>  [9,] -1.0719931
> [10,]  1.8537217
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> [1] "Result for  8"
> $beta
>             [,1]
>  [1,] -0.1172419
>  [2,] -0.1852151
>  [3,] -1.1407910
>  [4,]  0.1267308
>  [5,] -0.5048296
>  [6,] -1.4990974
>  [7,] -0.5366841
>  [8,] -1.1671009
>  [9,] -1.0822491
> [10,]  1.8596792
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>             [,1]
>  [1,] -0.1172419
>  [2,] -0.1852151
>  [3,] -1.1407910
>  [4,]  0.1267308
>  [5,] -0.5048296
>  [6,] -1.4990974
>  [7,] -0.5366841
>  [8,] -1.1671009
>  [9,] -1.0822491
> [10,]  1.8596792
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> [1] "Result for  9"
> $beta
>             [,1]
>  [1,] -0.1253119
>  [2,] -0.1744744
>  [3,] -1.1286001
>  [4,]  0.1280542
>  [5,] -0.5245776
>  [6,] -1.4732498
>  [7,] -0.5354316
>  [8,] -1.1706458
>  [9,] -1.0908596
> [10,]  1.8646205
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>             [,1]
>  [1,] -0.1253119
>  [2,] -0.1744744
>  [3,] -1.1286001
>  [4,]  0.1280542
>  [5,] -0.5245776
>  [6,] -1.4732498
>  [7,] -0.5354316
>  [8,] -1.1706458
>  [9,] -1.0908596
> [10,]  1.8646205
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> [1] "Result for  10"
> $beta
>             [,1]
>  [1,] -0.1321862
>  [2,] -0.1651825
>  [3,] -1.1180392
>  [4,]  0.1291370
>  [5,] -0.5415033
>  [6,] -1.4511217
>  [7,] -0.5344217
>  [8,] -1.1737051
>  [9,] -1.0981778
> [10,]  1.8687639
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
>
> $beta
>             [,1]
>  [1,] -0.1321862
>  [2,] -0.1651825
>  [3,] -1.1180392
>  [4,]  0.1291370
>  [5,] -0.5415033
>  [6,] -1.4511217
>  [7,] -0.5344217
>  [8,] -1.1737051
>  [9,] -1.0981778
> [10,]  1.8687639
>
> $cl
> pols(X = X, y = y, L = i)
> ```

Comment: `X` and `y` won't be in the global environment, necessarily.

Comment: @generic_user You can set or prepend the environment in that case. There's an example here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: What I really want to do is find ways of avoiding re-specifying a huge list of arguments.

Comment: @generic_user I'm confused about what you mean. It might be informative to add another example that's more reflective of what you're dealing with.

Comment: Well, the first thing I want is to extract the arguments from the call that I saved via `match.call()`.  Then I want to modify that information and use it to drive the function.  The function will be driven with a call.

Comment: @generic_user I'm sorry, I really don't follow. Someone else may come along who understands what you mean, but in general it's really preferable to include the issues you're dealing with in your example. Otherwise it's like trying to solve a riddle with half of the riddle missing. I am about to drive home for an hour but I'll check back later to see if there's any update to the example.